# how to do drag and drop an item from one listbox to another

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, listbox

Is it possible to drag and drop an item from one `Listbox` to another? not remove but copy. 
from this `Listbox`. Actually, I have three listboxes, they are quite similar and I need to be able to drop an item(one from each `Listbox`) to `Listbox` listHero

```
<ListBox x:Name="listhelmets" Height="214" Width="248" ItemsSource="{Binding ListHelmets}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Canvas.Left="464" Canvas.Top="37" PreviewMouseDown="helmet_MouseDown1"
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="helmet_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" DragLeave="helmet_DragLeave"
        PreviewMouseMove="helmet_PreviewMouseMove" SelectedValuePath="protection">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}" Width="56" Height="61"/>
                        <TextBox Height="30" Width="30">
                          <Binding Path="protection" />
                           </TextBox>
                       </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

to this one

```
 <ListBox x:Name="listHero" Height="148" Width="158" 
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                     </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Drag and drop for first listbox:

```
private void helmet_MouseDown1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);


}

private void helmet_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
    Vector diff = _startPoint - mousePos;
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
  (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
   Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
    {

        var listBox = sender as ListBox;
        var listBoxItem = listBox.SelectedItem;

        DataObject dragData = new DataObject(_dropIdentifier, listBoxItem);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listBox, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
```

Comment: And how are you planning to drag a Helmet in a list of Heros, could provide your model also

Comment: @SamTheDev what do you mean? my listhelmet is bound to observablecollection of helmets which provides listbox with helmets, I don't think it has anything to do with model, it has to do with accepting listbox events

Comment: so listHero will also contains a list of hemets ?

Comment: @SamTheDev not only, a have also a list of weapons and list of armature and I need to drag items from these lists to listHero, so it should contain 3 items

Answer (score 0):

[As MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdropeffects(v=vs.110).aspx) about enumeration `DragDropEffects`:

- **All** - The data is copied, removed from the drag source, and scrolled in
  the drop target.
- **Copy** - The data is copied to the drop target.
- **Link** - The data from the drag source is linked to the drop target.
- **Move** - The data from the drag source is moved to the drop target.
- **None** - The drop target does not accept the data.
- **Scroll** - Scrolling is about to start or is currently occurring in the drop target.

In order to just copy items you should just change the value `DragDropEffects` from `Move` to `Copy`:

```
private void helmet_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //the code omitted for the brevity
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
  (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
   Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
    {    
        //the code omitted for the brevity
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listBox, dragData, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox x:Name="DropList" 
          Drop="DropList_Drop" 
          DragEnter="DropList_DragEnter" 
          AllowDrop="True" />
```

**C#:**

```
private void DropList_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat") ||
        sender == e.Source)
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
}

    private void DropList_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat"))
    {
        Contact contact = e.Data.GetData("myFormat") as Contact;
        ListView listView = sender as ListView;
        listView.Items.Add(contact);
    }
}
```

Comment: but what about events for accepting listbox? @StepUp

Comment: can i replace Contact contact with Helmet in my case? and ListView listView with listhero? i replaced but nothing appears on listhero listbox @StepUp

Comment: have you changed 'DragDropEffects.Move' to 'Copy'? if earlier moving worked, then copy should work without changing event handler

Comment: yes i 've changed but for now it's better to have it as Remove as long as removed items dissapear from one listbox(hurray) but don't appear in another, what should i do to see it as an item in accepting listbox? @StepUp

Comment: I used this code but item still doesn't appear http://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/477112/3 @StepUp

Comment: what if in helmet_PreviewMouseMove i write var data = new DataObject("Helmet", str);
and the in listHero_Drop a wrote  var str = e.Data.GetData("Helmet") as Helmet;
         
         var lst = sender as ListBox;
        (lst.ItemsSource as IList).Add(str);
         listHero.Items.Add(e.Data.GetData("Helmet") as Helmet);
i  have nullreferenceexceprion here ItemsSource as IList @StepUp

Comment: @NickShepard see this tutorial. Maybe it will help to you
http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/drag-and-drop/